# Select поля в PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Как осуществить, Select поле в PHP?
К примеру если необходимо выбрать определенный цвет из списка. Выбранный цвет в последствии должен быть закинуть в определенное поле в БД.

Comment: Что значит - осуществить? Вы не можете написать `<select><option>...` или что?

Comment: А так вариант?
function GetColorArray(){
 $tlist = color_identifiers_list();
/*
 $tlist2 = array(
  'Red' => 'Красный',
  'Black' => 'Черный',
);

Comment: Что значит - `Вариант`?

Comment: Ну т.е. через массив значения сделать, чтобы они выпадали как список. Дело в том, что мне нужно чисто в php варианте это осуществить.

Comment: Ну сделайте через массив, я просто не понимаю о чем вопрос, в чем тут проблема?

Comment: А вот вам код

`<form action = "7.php" method="post"> 
    <select name="student"> 
    <option value = "">Выберите студента: 
    <?php 
        $i = 0; 
        while ( $i < sizeof($people) ) : 
            print "<option 
            value='$people[$i]'>$people[$i]"; 
            $i++; 
        endwhile; 
    ?> 
    </select> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вот вам код

```
<form action = "7.php" method="post"> 
<select name="student"> 
<option value = "">Выберите студента: 
<?php 
    $i = 0; 
    while ( $i < sizeof($people) ) : 
        print "<option 
        value='$people[$i]'>$people[$i]"; 
        $i++; 
    endwhile; 
?> 
</select>
```

---

Ответ из комментария @RussCoder.